# Tests for Event Listeners sendin email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I'm quite new to testing so any help would be appreciated. First things first, this is my code inside App directory (Laravel 5.5)

```
// controller
public function store(Request $request)
{    
        $foo = new Foo($request->only([
            'email', 
            'value 2', 
            'value 3',
        ]));
        $foo->save();

        event(new FooCreated($foo));

        return redirect()->route('/');
}

// Events/FooCreated
use App\Foo;

class FooCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $foo;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}


// Listeners/

use App\Events\FooCreated;
use App\Mail\FooSendingEmail;

class EmailSendListener
{

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  EnquiryWasCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(FooCreated $event)
    {
        \Mail::to($event->foo->email)->send(new FooSendingEmail($event->foo));
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write some tests for the event and the listener that triggers the email to sent, so I have created a method in unit/ExampleTest.php

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use App\Foo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use App\Events\FooCreated;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    public function testEventTriggered(){
        Event::fake();

        $foo = factory(\App\Foo::class)->create();

        Event::assertDispatched(FooCreated::class, function($event) use ($foo){
             return $event->foo->id == $foo->id;
        });
    }
}

// assume similar this applies for emails according to docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mail-fake
```

but when I run this test, fails with error `The expected [App\Events\FooEvent] event was not dispatched. Failed asserting that false is true.`

How can I fix the testfor events to pass and also to test sending email ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to add a test for firing the event on controller, but I 'd need a test for checking the emails are triggered

```
public function testStore()
{
        Event::fake();

        $this->post(route('foo.store'), [
            'full_name' => 'John Doe',
            'email'     => 'johndoe@example.com',
            'body'      => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        ]);

        $foo = Foo::first();

        Event::assertDispatched(FooCreated::class, function ($event) use ($foo) {
            return $event->foo->id === $foo->id;
        });
}


public function testEmailSent()
{
        Mail::fake();
        // similar to prevous one in order to fire the event
        $this->post(route('foo.store'), [
            'full_name' => 'John Doe',
            'email'     => 'johndoe@example.com',
            'body'      => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'reference_code' => str_random(25),
        ]);

        $foo = Foo::first();

        Mail::assertSent(FooSendingEmail::class, function ($mail) use ($foo) {
            return $mail->hasTo($foo->email);
        });
}
```

Comment: Where is the `FooEvent` class defined? Seems like it should be `FooCreated` instead.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the code, I misspelled it

Comment: But the error is still there though

Comment: The event is being fired from the `store()` method of your controller. But in the test your calling the `create()` method of your model. I don't think the `store()` method is being call.

Comment: The event is in controller method `store()` not within `Foo::create()`, so basically I insert new record in db and then trigger the event to send email

Comment: If the event is fired from within `store()` but `store()` is never called in your test, I don't see how the event could be being fired.

Comment: As Camilo says - that is why you should put the event in the model

Comment: I see, how can I call `store()` in my test then? is its by `$this->post(route('foo.store'))`?

Comment: I would have one test that checks the event gets fired by the controller, and another that fires the event and checks the right actions are triggered

Comment: @MatthewDaly I have manage to do the first part like you said, however I 'm trying to write a test for checking the email from the lister is fired. how can I do this? I have also updated the code

Comment: @Lykos Have a look at the [docs for mocking the mail facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mail-fake). What you need to do is set it up to mock the mail facade, fire the event, then assert that the email was sent.

Comment: I have updated the code to review. Basically I have done same thing as with the event test, I access the controller method in order to fire the event, but the test fails with error `mailable was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.`

Comment: @Lykos No, when you test the event's functionality, you fire it in the test itself - don't call the controller. You want to test the event in isolation.

Comment: Do you want to move in chat to give me some additional help, because I haven't much experience with tests, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163970/discussion-between-lykos-and-matthew-daly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, my advice would be to write one test for the controller, and another for the event listener. Since ultimately you don't know if that event may be removed from that controller in future, it makes sense to test the controller and listener classes in isolation.

Here's how I would test these classes:

## Testing the controller method

The controller method does three things:

- Return a response
- Create a model instance
- Fire an event

We therefore need to pass it all its external dependencies and check it carries out the required actions.

First we fake the event facade:

```
Event::fake();
```

Next step is to create an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` to represent the HTTP request passed to the controller:

```
$request = Request::create('/store', 'POST',[
    'foo' => 'bar'
]);
```

If you're using a custom form request class, you should instantiate that in exactly the same way.

Then, instantiate the controller, and call the method, passing it the request object:

```
$controller = new MyController();
$response = $controller->store($request);
```

It makes sense to then test the response from the controller. You can test the status code like this:

```
$this->assertEquals(302, $response->getStatusCode());
```

You may also want to check the content of the response matches what you expect to see.

You will then want to retrieve the newly created model instance, and verify it exists:

```
$foo = Foo::where('foo', 'bar')->first();
$this->assertNotNull($foo);
```

You can also use `assertEquals()` to check the attributes on the model if appropriate. Finally, you check the event was fired:

```
Event::assertDispatched(FooWasCreated::class, function ($event) use ($foo) { 
    return $event->foo->id === $foo->id; 
});
```

This test should not concern itself with any functionality triggered by the event, only that the event gets triggered.

## Testing the event listener

Since all the event listener does is send an email when passed an event, we should test that it calls the Mail facade with the correct arguments. The first step is to fake the mail facade:

```
Mail::fake();
```

Then, create an instance of your model - you can use Eloquent but it's usually more convenient to use a factory:

```
$foo = factory(Foo::class)->create([]);
```

Then, trigger your event:

```
event(new FooCreated($foo));
```

Finally, assert the mail facade received a request with the appropriate arguments:

```
Mail::assertSent(MyEmail::class, function ($mail) use ($foo) { 
    return $mail->foo->id == $foo->id; 
});
```

Technically, these don't quite qualify as being unit tests because they hit the database, but they should cover the controller and event adequately.

To make them true unit tests, you'd need to implement the repository pattern for the database queries rather than using Eloquent directly and mock the repository, so you can assert that the mocked repository receive the right data and have it return a mock of the model. [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) would be useful for this.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: This is a great explanation with practical examples. It reinforces the approach where unit tests should wrap around the smallest units practical.

Answer (score 1):

You arent firing the event `FooEvent` its `FooCreated` and you are not calling the method on the controller that actually dispatches the event (at least not in the code you are showing).

```
// controller
public function store(Request $request)
 {    
    $foo = Foo::create($request->only([
        'email', 
        'value 2', 
        'value 3',
    ]));

    return redirect()->route('/');
}


// Foo model
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = parent::create($attributes);

    event(new FooCreated($foo));

    return $model;

}

///test
public function testEventTriggered()
{
    $foo = factory(\App\Foo::class)->create();

    Event::fake();

    Event::assertDispatched(FooCreated::class, function($event) use ($foo){
         return $event->foo->id == $foo->id;
    });

}
```

Or add a new method if you don't want to fire your event all the time:

```
// Foo model
public static function createWithEvent(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = parent::create($attributes);

    event(new FooCreated($foo));

    return $model;

}
```

Comment: The event is located inside the controller method. Can't I have a test method for testing this event as separate unit? or maybe as a feature?

Comment: You are better off keeping your controller skinny and containing the logic in the model and testing that. Otherwise you need to mock a request and test the controller method (which you are not doing and therefore not seeing the event)

Comment: The reason why I want to keep the event in controller is because I'm also using `Foo::create` somewhere else and I don't want to fire the event at this point.

Comment: Simply add a new method to your model then

Comment: @Lykos i made an edit to show how simple that would be